# Why does Oracle SQL Developer use such strange delete criteria?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When deleting rows in the grid view, the message panel indicates that SQL Developer issues this delete command.

```
DELETE FROM "MH"."T" WHERE ROWID = 'AABUG+AAEAAEZtrAAA'
                       AND ORA_ROWSCN = '1220510600909'
                       and ( "A" is null or "A" is not null )
```

It seems specifying the ROWID should be sufficient to identify the row, so

- Why does it specify ORA_ROWSCN?
- And more befuddling, why the is null / not null clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ROWID` is just the physical address of the row.  If one row is deleted and another row is inserted, the new row could have the same `ROWID` as the old row.  If the data in the row had been modified, it is also possible that its `ROWID` could have changed.  The `ORA_ROWSCN` criteria ensures that neither of these have actually happened.  It also allows SQL Developer to alert you if another session had modified the data since you read it so that you can confirm that you still want to delete the row.

I'm at a loss for what the `A is null or A is not null` predicate would be adding.  If it was the first predicate, I would guess that it was the standard `1 = 1` predicate that folks sometimes add to queries that are dynamically built to simplify the process of building the SQL statement dynamically.  But that doesn't fit with it being the last predicate in the query.  Is `A` the primary key of the table?

Comment: worth mentioning that usage of `ora_rowscn` as a versioning column for optimistic locking implementation doesn't make sense without `rowdependencies` specified for a table - without it the tool thinks that all rows in the same block were changed

Comment: @beherenow - Without `rowdependencies`, the value is tracked at the block level.  It's still useful for implementing optimistic locking, there is just a greater risk of a false positive.  Optimistic locking already has to accept the potential for a false positive (say someone updates the row without changing any data).

Comment: Thanks Justin, that makes a lot of sense!